# What is the use of Message-ID in email?

Tags: email, smtp, uniqueidentifier

From what I've read, every Message-ID must be unique, however it is possible to create repeated Message-IDs if we force the header with a fixed value. So I don't understand what the point of them saying that the Message-ID should be unique, but they are very easy to create duplicates. If they can easily be generated by anyone with a little reading and basic programmatic knowledge, why do Message-IDs exist and what are they used for, which I can easily duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.4

in conjunction with the `References` and `In-Reply-To` fields, mail clients use `Message-ID` to organize multiple messages into threads.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID

and at least some clients will consider two messages with the same ID to be the same thing and discard one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: For threading in email clients.

The `message-id` header is defined in [RFC 2822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.4):

> The "Message-ID:" field contains a single unique message identifier.
> The "References:" and "In-Reply-To:" field each contain one or more
> unique message identifiers

The message ID is used to show which message is a reply to which other message, for example. That way mail clients can show a tree of emails with their replies even if other things like the `Subject` don't change. (Counting leading `Re:`s of the subject line would be a bad way to determine ancestors and children: not every mail client adds them, and some use language specific ones.)

Answer (score 0):

> So I don't understand what the point of them saying that the Message-ID should be unique, but they are very easy to create duplicates.

It's like with programming languages (assuming you have some basic idea about programming): You *can* store multiple different things in one global variable, and that *might* work, or it won't:
If you want your program to work reliably, *don't do that!*

There is no global Internet or Intranet police that will catch such messages, preventing malfunction of the system.

Instead, as others pointed out, the unique ID is to identify a message uniquely within a pool of many (maybe all) messages.

One situation where it may be important is "mail-loop prevention":
If you send 100 messages withing one second, all using the same Message-ID, the following 99 may be discarded, because they are the "same" message as per definition.